# how to put a location name programmatically in Google JS autocomplete API and get the results?

Tags: javascript, api, autocomplete

When searching for Edinburgh napier university using google autocomplete API, I don't get the state and city, which should be scotland and edinburgh.

I want that if the result doesn't include city and state, it takes the postal town name (which in our case is edinbrugh) and search for the state and city of the postal town, then include them as city and state of Edinburgh napier university.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name',
  postal_town: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')));
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }

  if(locality.value == '' && administrative_area_level_1.value == '') {
    if(postal_town.value != '') {
        <!--- What to place here? -->
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

    </script>

    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Postal town</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="postal_town" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">state2</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a system for the zip codes?  Can you (human) see which country of the UK corresponds to a zip code (Edit your question if you can't respond)?  Because you are right, Google does not send "Scotland" in any result component.

Comment: I tried searching for "University of the West of Scotland", it shows the state as scotland and the country as UK. It does show Scotland sometimes. Yes there is a system of zip codes, though it is not always retrievable. But my question is what if for some reason, it fails to retrieve city or state, then I need another solution to find the information.

Comment: Yes, then you should pass the city to another search engine, that returns the country.  I think this API could be the solution: http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api . Or you have some list with cities/zip codes with their country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something, as I mentioned in the comments I pass the value through an API that searches for city details.

Look at function getUkCountry().

That function tries out the four regions/countries of the UK.
It works for the case you mentioned, it works for Westminster.  I'm not really happy with the script, but it's something

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name',
  postal_town: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')));
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  if($('#administrative_area_level_1').val() == '') {
    getUkCountry($('#postal_town').val(), 0);
  }
}
  function getUkCountry(city, i) {
    var countries = ['EN', 'SC', 'NI', 'WA'];
    if (i>=countries.length) {
      return false;
    }
    // Here is an API that gets address components
    // http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api
    $.getJSON(
      "http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?&fqcn=" + city + ', ' + countries[i] + ', United Kingdom' ,
      function (data) {
        if (! data.geobytesregion) {
          getUkCountry(city, i+1);
        }
        $('#administrative_area_level_1').val(data.geobytesregion);
      }
    );
  }
// [END region_fillform]
    </script>
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <p>
      Try to search for these:<br>
      Edinburgh napier university<br>
      Westminster Abbey
    </p>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Postal town</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="postal_town" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">state2</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is perfect, works everytime. I have the state, and the city will be the postal town, and then all the fields are filled. Thank you very much, I learned a lot from you.

Comment: Nice to know that api works fine,  I could use that some day